# Trying to timeit a function

Tags: python

```
# coding: utf-8



def recherche_v1(x,tab):
    """
    tab est une liste d'éléments de types quelconques
    La fonction retourne True si x est dans tab, et false sinon
    """
    reponse = False
    for i in range(len(tab)):
        if tab[i] == x:
            reponse = True
    return reponse


def recherche_v2(x,tab):
    """
    tab est une liste d'éléments de types quelconques
    La fonction retourne True si x est dans tab, et false sinon
    """
    i = 0
    n = len(tab)
    while i < n and tab[i] != x:
        i = i + 1
    if i < n:
        return True
    else:
        return False


import timeit

x=int(input("saisir x : "))

print(timeit.timeit("recherche_v1(x,tab)", setup="from __main__ import recherche_v1", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("recherche_v2(x,tab)", setup="from __main__ import recherche_v2", number=100000))
```

Im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Bureau/Nouveau dossier (3)/fcts_recherche_occur.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(timeit.timeit("recherche_v1(x,tab)", setup="from __main__ import recherche_v1", number=100000))
  File "C:\Users\arman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\timeit.py", line 232, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "C:\Users\arman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\timeit.py", line 176, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide *all* names you use in your timed code, in the setup. You currently only provide the `recherche_v1` name, but not `x` or `tab`. Import those *too*:

```
tab = [...]  # you need to provide an object for the `tab` variable

print(
    timeit.timeit(
        "recherche_v1(x,tab)",
        setup="from __main__ import recherche_v1, x, tab",
        number=100000)
)
```

You have not defined `tab` anywhere, you'll need to provide a value for that separately.

Provided you are using Python 3.5 or newer, you could consider using the `globals` dictionary argument to `timeit.timeit()`, instead of using `from __main__ import ...` in a `setup` string:

```
print(
    timeit.timeit(
        "recherche_v1(x,tab)",
        globals={
            'recherche_v1': recherche_v1,
            'x': x,
            'tab': [...],   # a list value for tab is also needed
        },
        number=100000
    )
)
```

In either case, if you want to compare the performance of your two functions, consider *generating* a list of random values of a fixed, large, length, and picking `x` from the generated result. You want to compare different scenarios here and compare their timings:

- `x` *not* being in the `tab` list
- `x` being the first value in `tab`
- `x` as the last value in `tab`

and you may want to compare these for `tab` lengths that grow by a magnitude each; so lists of length 1.000, 10.000, 100.000, etc.

There are some other issues you may want to address:

- If you are using `if <boolean test>: return True`, `else: return False`, **just return the `boolean test` result**. So, in your case, instead of using:

  ```
  if i < n:
      return True
  else:
      return False
  ```

  You could just use

  ```
  return i < n
  ```

  and get the same result
- In `recherche_v1` are generating an index value between `i` and `len(tab)` with `range(len(tab))`, but then only use that index to get the values from `tab`. Rather than use a `for` loop on a `range()`, just loop *on the list itself*:

  ```
  for value in tab:
      if value == x:
  ```

I'm not sure if your goal is to compare how `while` compares to using a `for` loop, or if exiting the loop early makes a difference. If the latter, consider using `return` inside the loop; the moment you have found an equal value, you can exit your function with `return True`.

And finally, do also compare your functions against `def recherche_integre(x, tab): return x in tab`, for the built-in membership test for list objects.

Comment: Ty for the help.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept **one** of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-) Which one you pick is entirely up to you, and not picking any is also a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

`timeit.timeit` doesn't know about the name `x` because it only exists in the main code, not in `setup` or `globals`. You should explicitly provide it:

```
timeit.timeit(
    "recherche_v1(x,tab)",
    globals={
        'recherche_v1': recherche_v1,  # name from main code
        'x': x,   # name from main code
        'tab': ... # you never defined `tab`
    },
    number=100000
)
```

You could also import these names in `setup`, as you're doing now.

Comment: Ty for the help.